# why do I get ERR 404 on 'npm install ibmconfig'? #bluemix nodejs server

Tags: node.js, npm, ibm-cloud

I downloaded my IBM bluemix nodeJS app, and trying to install all the dependencies of the project. For some reason, `ibmconfig` is throwing an exception. However, the URL works fine from the browser. Looks like a npm registry exception.This module is a dependency for `ibmsecurity`.

Here is the package.json dependency content:

```
"dependencies": {
      "express": "4.*",
      "body-parser": "*",
      "ibmsecurity": "*",
      "twilio": "*",
      "ibmbluemix":"*",
      "ibmdata":"*"
   }
```

Here is the 404 exception:

```
npm WARN package.json @ license should be a valid SPDX license expression
npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "ibmconfig"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/ibmconfig
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'ibmconfig' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although that registry file still exists, if you go to the [ibmconfig package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibmconfig) you'll see that it does not exist.  I suspect that the package has been unpublished.  You may have to contact the original maintainer to find out what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Review of the `ibmsecurity` npm package's Git log for the `package.json` file, it looks like the dependency on an `ibmconfig` package was removed on 2015-07-29.  You may need to update the package with `npm update ibmsecurity`

Answer (score 1):

You will only see this error if you use the beta version of ibmsecurity (0.3.x). Change your dependency to use "latest" or "1.0.x" and you will not have this problem.